# For each $\alpha>0$ there exists a zero dimensional ideal $I$ such that $\dim_K(R/I) - |V(I)| \geq \alpha$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $I \subset K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a zero dimensional ideal and $$V(I) = \{ (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \in K^n: f((\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)) = 0\ \forall f\in I\}$$ (the variety).

> I know that $|V(I)| \leq \dim_K(R/I)$, but can the gap $\dim_K(R/I) - |V(I)|$ be made arbitrary large? That is, $\forall \alpha > 0$, is there a zero-dimensional ideal such that $$\dim_K(R/I) - |V(I)| \geq \alpha\ ?$$

I thought about lower cases, so $n = 1$ gives me $I = (0)$ and $V(I) =\mathbb A^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $I=(x,y)^d$ in $K[x,y]$. Then $|V(I)|=1$ and $\dim_KR/I=\frac{d(d+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Does $(x,y)^d = (x^d, y^d)$? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @jacobsmith No. $(x,y)^d=(x^d,x^{d-1}y,\dots,xy^{d-1},y^d)$

Comment: This is probably the point of your answer, but can you elaborate on $dim R/I = d(d + 1)/2$, thanks for your help.

Comment: @jacobsmith When take the quotient $R/I$ and look at the monomial basis of $R$ over $K$, then the only surviving monomials are $x^iy^j$ with $i+j<d$ and these are exactly...

Comment: How did you come up with your $I$?

Comment: $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal and every power of this give rise to a zero-dimensional ideal since the ring $K[x,y]/(x,y)^d$ is artinian for all $d\ge1$.

Comment: Note that you can take any zero-dimensional ideal and the gap between $\dim R/I^d$ and $\# \mathcal V(I^d)$ will get arbitrary large, since the latter is constant and the former is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers...